# which word sounds natural? (common/usual/regular)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I google a lot about the meaning of these words, but I could not find out what is the best choice for my sentence?

kings decided in the dictator manner without listening to others' advice. Therefore, deciding quickly without consultation was ....(regular/common/usual)

Comment: Where did you find these sentences?

Answer (score 0):

Kings' decisions were very unilateral. Therefore, making quick decisions without consulting anyone used to be very **common** for kings in their time.

or

Kings' decisions were very unilateral. Therefore, making quick decisions without consulting anyone used to be very **usual** for kings in their time.